# Rendering ascii image in jsx component

Tags: reactjs, ascii

Hello I'm trying to render the following ascii image in a react jsx component but getting a Parsing error: Unexpected token. I wonder if I have to escape some of the characters?

```
<pre id="taag_output_text" style="float:left;" class="fig" contenteditable="true">   _     _   
  (c).-.(c)  
   / ._. \   
 __\( Y )/__ 
(_.-/'-'\-._)
   || T ||   
 _.' `-' '._ 
(.-./`-'\.-.)
 `-'     `-'
</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things which are wrong here:
 1. `style` has to be an object.
 2. You will need to use template literal strings to preserve the linebreaks.
 3. you will need to escape/replace the backticks.

Putting this should work:

```
      <pre
        id="taag_output_text"
        style={{ float: "left" }}
        class="fig"
        contenteditable="true"
      >
        {`
          _     _   
          (c).-.(c)  
           / ._. \   
         __\( Y )/__ 
        (_.-/'-'\-._)
           || T ||   
         _.' \`-' '._ 
        (.-./\`-'\.-.)
         \`-'    \`-'
          `}
      </pre>
```